# Is the derivation of the transfer function of this circuit correct?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]
I know it is simple, but I wonder if it is correct since the feedback resistor seems to be of limited use for the bias current regularly very small. Its considered under the assumptions of the ideal model.

[Buffer with feddback resistance](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZYA4BsB2ATNzZsEBOVA9EBSCiqhAUwFowwAoAQ3CO3E3IGZsVMLxCpwSJkjDx4IPtGxElWeAKVFMc6H3AzILYdzBdORgCxnTUEJvk6kVR9CQBSbACEQANQD2AGwAXNgBzOhYAeTlBHn50MWFyCH0AdyihEQEhAigWVOMjbPzwdEcWACcrZm5M5G4heBYgA)

[image]

\$I_{1}=I_{2}\$

\$\frac{V_{1}-0}{R_{I}}=\frac{0-V_{o}}{R_{f}}\$

\$\frac{V_{1}}{R_{I}}=\frac{-V_{o}}{R_{f}}\$

\$\frac{R_{f}}{R_{I}}=\frac{-V_{o}}{V_{i}}\$

\$\frac{V_{o}}{V_{i}}=-\frac{R_{f}}{R_{I}}\$

\$V_{s}=-\frac{R_{f}}{R_{I}}V_{e}\$
That seems to be fine, except that the voltage is expected to be inverted.

Comment: Where does the 0 come from, and why do you say that the two currents should be equal?

Comment: @corie lookup up the inverting and non inverting fitness of opamps, the opamps above has no feedback

Comment: You need to label \$V_s\$, \$V_e\$, \$I_s\$, and \$I_e\$ in your schematic. Be sure to indicate the direction of the currents. What assumptions are you making about whether or not the op amp is ideal?

Comment: Corie, all bipolar (and even FET based ones) have bias currents. (They also have offset currents, which are the unavoidable differences between inputs.) They need these to operate. Suppose you have a source voltage with a source impedance (represented by your +3.3 V input and the resistor as shown.) Then there will be a slight voltage difference at the (+) input -- it won't quite be +3.3 V. Assuming \$V_{_\text{OS}}=0\:\text{V}\$ (ignoring offset voltage as a separate issue), to get the output to match +3.3 V you will also want a similar tiny difference. The feedback resistance provides it.

Comment: Corie, whether you do it or not is up to you, though. Only you know if it is enough of an improvement to be worth the added part.

Comment: Of course, I will update the schematic, and take in consideration the valuable comments here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the op amp is assumed to be ideal then there is no need to compensate for the bias currents, and we conclude that no current passes through either of the resistors. Thus there is no voltage across them and they can be replaced with wires. What is left a canonical voltage follower.